# Include code from different function in PHP

Tags: php, macros, include

I have a library from C I'm adapting to PHP. There are no macros in PHP, but I need something similar. Let me give you a quick example:

```
function check($test){
   if($test == false) return;
}
```

And I call such function inside another a few times:

```
function checks(){
   check(0==1);
   check(1==1);
   ...
}
```

And I'd want the checks function to stop after the first test. Please note that this is not exactly what I'm trying to do, this is just an example so you can understand what I'm looking for. The return statement in "check" should make the function "checks" return.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Not possible. You will have to do this inside `checks` by inspecting the return value of `check`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this..,

```
<?php

    function check($test) {
        if($test == FALSE) {
            //do Something..
            exit();
        }
    }

    function checks() {
        check(1 == 1);
        echo "1 Done..</br>";
        check(2 == 2);
        echo "2 Done..</br>";
        check(0 == 0);
        echo "3 Done..</br>";
        check(1 == 2);
        echo "4 Done..</br>";
        check(1 == 0);
        echo "5 Done..</br>";
        check(2 == 1);  
        echo "6 Done..</br>";
    }

    checks();
?>
```

Comment: It kills entire page / script, but not a parent function. Still, if it`s an option...

Comment: Yes. I ended up using this, because even though it was more global than I needed I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to completely reproduce such behaviour in PHP. But, `try {} catch () {}` block might help.

```
<?php
define('SAFE_RETURN', 8795);

function scream($condition){
   if($condition)throw new Exception('', SAFE_RETURN);
}

function checks(){
   try {
      scream(1 == 0);
      echo 1;

      scream(0 == 1);
      echo 2;

      scream(1 == 1);
      echo 3;

   } catch(Exception $e){ if($e->getCode() != SAFE_RETURN)throw $e; };
}

checks();
?>
```

Comment: I suppose there isn't a way to do exactly what I want in that case, but this is close enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that can be done in php, but you could do something like:

```
function check($test){
    if($test == false) 
        return false;
    return true;
}

function checks(){
   if check(0==1) return;
   if check(1==1) return;

}
```

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood horribly?

Comment: That would definitely work for that example, but what I actually need is some way to run the code of an external function as if it that code was running inside the function which calls it :)